# Iterating spatial join with multiple merge rules (and then creating raster) in ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, spatial-join, iterator, rasterization

I'm using a Basic licence in ArcGIS Desktop 10.3 with Spatial & 3D Analyst extensions.

I have a dbf file which contains point data for several days.  I want my final output to be

> a) a point feature class for each day.
>
> b) A polygon feature class for each day with stats (e.g.: minimum, mean and maximum) for those points within a cell in a hexagon
>   grid.
>
> c) A raster based on the mean value in each cell for those days.

I've got as far as having the individual point feature classes for each day (using a couple of python scripts within a model) but I am stuck on getting the iteration right for the Spatial Join and Rasters to be created.

I can't see how I can tell the model that I want the name(s) to be in a certain format.

For the Feature Classes that result from the Spatial Join I want to use the original input Feature Class name with "_SJHexGrid" appended to it.

Then for the rasters that are generated from those "_SJHexGrid" files I would want to append with "_MeanRast".

This is a diagram of the model as it currently stands (the "(wildcard)" in the Name input is just to show I am using a wildcard for illustration purposes here).

[image: Iteration model for spatial join and raster creation]

Comment: If you are using modelbuilder and an iterator and the output is overwriting then the issue is almost certainly to do with the output name and you not using inline substitution. On each iteration you need to feed the name coming out of the iterator into the output name in your tool. Search help or here for inline substitution.

Comment: Please decide whether you wish to ask about ModelBuilder or ArcPy in this particular question, and then [edit] it to focus on that part of the Geiprocessing Framework.  You can always ask about the other part in a separate question.  For ModelBuilder questions please include a picture of your model.  For ArcPy questions please include a code snippet that illustrates what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: As your model stands the output of spatial join would be something like `c:\temp\xyz\%Name (wildcard)%_SJHexGrid.shp`, May be you should rename the name output of the iterator to simply `Name` for ease of use?

Comment: the "(wildcard)" part on the diagram was just included as an indication to what I was trying to do for explanation here.  The it's actually "PtHghts2*" in the iterator. Also I'm working in a file geodatabase, not shapefiles in the model you see here.

Comment: And I can't see how I am telling the Iterator what I actually want it to call the output feature classes. At the moment it is just overwriting ones it created for previous iterations.

Comment: So when you are looking at your model you see the word "PtHghts2*" in the light green blob? If so then the spatial join output is set to `c:\temp\mygb.gdb\%PtHghts2*%_SJHexGrid`? You do understand that what you see on the model canvas is the name and it's whats inside it that is the value being passed around the model?

Comment: The light green blob was just called "Name" on the canvas - I just modified that and didn't change the value (it was greyed out anyway once I had set the wildcard from the iterator).  I'll double check by redoing it, just in case I did something stupid.

Comment: So it is "Name" that is the name of that variable so if you right click on the output of the spatial join and open it then set that variable to `c:\temp\mygb.gdb\%Name%_SJHexGrid` but obviously setting the correct path. You are using inline variable substitution. If the variable coming out was renamed by you to "bob" then it would be c:\temp\mygb.gdb\%bob%_SJHexGrid and bob is what ever value that is being spat out by the iterator.

Comment: That works brilliantly but is there any way to make it so that I don't have to hard code the path in the variable? I want to use this as a template model which can be moved to various places in a shared area so it really needs to be a relative path.